# Python - figure settings in plotting loop

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, matplotlib

[image]Hi
I have a little problem, I made a loop which creates 3 plots in every iteration and set text 
on x label to be rotated but it works only for last fig in a row. I am not sure how to affect first and second figure.

```
  def multi_scatter(x_list, y):
    sns.set(style='whitegrid', rc={"grid.linewidth": 0.2})
    sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2)  
    for x in range(0, len(x_list)):
      if x == 0 or x % 3:
        chart = sns.pairplot(data=ds_train,
        y_vars=[y],
        x_vars=[x_list[x], x_list[x+1], x_list[x+2]],
        height = 10)
        plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
        plt.show()
      else:
        continue
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase you defined `chart` but never extract the axes from `chart`. You need to specify what the axes are in order to set xticklabels. Try to add these lines in your code (see the inner `for` loop):

```
def multi_scatter(x_list, y):
    sns.set(style='whitegrid', rc={"grid.linewidth": 0.2})
    sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2)  
    for x in range(0, len(x_list)):
        if x == 0 or x % 3:
            chart = sns.pairplot(data=ds_train,
                                 y_vars=[y],
                       x_vars=[x_list[x], x_list[x+1], x_list[x+2]],
                       height = 10)
            for ax in chart.axes.flat:
                 ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45 )

         else:
             continue
```

I did not test it without access to your data, so please let me know if it works!

Comment: Thank You for response. I tried Your code and end up with an error:
TypeError: multi_scatter_2() got multiple values for argument 'x_list'...


my inputs for this method always will be:
y - string
x_list - list of strings

Comment: Ok, rotation works right now, but x axis is from 0 to 1 on every plot, which is not good at all

Comment: I modified my answer, could you try it once? The original x-axis labels should stay as they are now.